# How to split git conflict file into two without git or git repository?

Tags: git, conflict

I have a git conflict file, i.e. a file, marked up as

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
foo
=======
bar
>>>>>>> cb1abc6bd98cfc84317f8aa95a7662815417802d
```

I would like to split this file into two to pass it to `GUI` diff tool I like.

How can I do this? Note, that I have no access to a repository, which has created this file, so I can't use `git` features directly.

Also I don't want to write splitter myself. Prefer to use standard tools.

Comment: Do you use `bash` or `cmd`?

Comment: `bash` user here :D

Comment: P.S. But I don't want to use common text processing tools, I would like to find standartized solution

Comment: Your best bet it to use git meld and then copy and paste the content of the two files where you need them. But git meld is quite ok already